# Import part of SQL dump to base

Tags: sql, dump

I have a SQL dump 5Gb size. Is there a possibility import from SQL dump only schemes tables and 5...10 records from each table.

Or maybe somebody knows any solution how to reduce SQL dump and save only table schemes and a few records for each table.

Comment: Possible solution is to create script or export script from the table, select 5-10 records of the each

Comment: I have only dump. And my working server don't have resource for 5Gb base.

Comment: It depends on the database.  If you're using PostgreSQL and the dump was produced by pg_dump then the dump file is readable and you can copy out the parts you want.  We really need to know the database product you are using to answer this question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I have MySQL database